# r - Replace NAs with values according to two index vectors

Tags: r, na, r-sp, spatial-data-frame

I have a spatial points data frame with characteristics of houses sold spanning through several years.
I appended to it neighborhood attributes using "over" in {sp}. For each year of my housing data there is a neighborhood´s data set joined.

The problem: neighborhood data for different years don't always contain the same variables. Therefore, when joined to the housing data, I obtain NAs in these non-shared variables for houses sold in some particular years.

Ideal solution: for each row in my data, replace NAs with same column data (V1) from the same neighborhood (nb) but closest year available (y).

```
      [,y]  [,nb] [,V1]
 [1,] 1993 30000 2752
 [2,] 1993 30000 2752
 [3,] 1994 30000 NA
 [4,] 1994 50000 2554
 [5,] 1995 30000 NA
 [6,] 1996 30000 2650
 [7,] 1996 50000 NA
```

Ideally, replace NAs such that `[3,V1] = 2752`; `[5,V1] = 2650`, and `[7,V1] = 2554`. The data frame contains over 250k obs so looping through the whole thing is rather cumbersome.

Comment: "most recent year available", would that not mean `[3,V1] = 2650` or do you mean the year closest to that missing? If the latter then do you prioritize a year greater than or less than the year in question?

Comment: I prioritize the closest year, be it past or future to the actual data point being replaced. Therefore, `[3,V1]=2752`, since the closest value of `V1` for `nb == 30000` in year 1994 is given in year 1993.

Comment: I understand what you did, You just didn't actually say that.

Comment: See what you mean, just edited it, instead of most recent put closest, which doesn't imply past years. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function below for your purpose.

```
get_rid_of_NAs <- function(urmatrix) {
  myvector <- vector()
  counter <- 0
  myvector_1 <- vector()

  for(i in 1:nrow(urmatrix)){
   out <- urmatrix[i,2]
   out_1 <- urmatrix[i,1]
   myvector_1 <- c(myvector_1,out_1)
   myvector <- c(myvector,out)

   if(urmatrix[i,3]!=NA){
   next
   }      
   orders <- order(myvector[myvector==out],decreasing=TRUE)
   index <- which.min(myvector_1[orders])    
   urmatrix[i,3] <- urmatrix[index,3]
   }
 return(urmatrix)
}
```

Now use the function to compute.

```
           get_rid_of_NAs(ENTERYOURMATRIXHERE.)
```

R can easily handle such a loop, but i would suggest the for loop in this case.

Seriously there are many people here saying "there aer 10min data r cant handle etc etc." R is not excel, R is created to handle the data

Comment: Need to edit this a bit sorry about that. By the way, I got a data frame from project gutenberg which is over 770k observations. I applied the function and it took like 5 seconds. Don't judge the R please, before asking for something make sure your premise is correct, don't just throw away what you think, make sure it is VALID.

Comment: Thank you Xenidia, I will try this out. My object is a spatial points object which is not a simple matrix, the structure is more complicated, and it has 345 variables and I need to apply this kind of function for more than 80 of them. Also, I am working with large spatial matrices that take up way too much memory so everything is slower. That is why I said cumbersome: I was thinking of a one liner for all of the variables, should have detail this, but I certainly would not want to judge R on the basis of it not being able to handle data, I will be more careful in the future.

Comment: Sorry Xenidia, but I do not get how out and out_1 work here. I get `Error: object 'out' not found`. Have you applied the function as it is?

Comment: no , youhave to define them within the function of course , wait let me edit

Comment: if any more problems exists let me know.

Comment: By the way, main purpose of me helping here is not to give you away the code for it. You should study the code and write your own one. This isn't the place for such a thing. I know you didn't mean to do it, but seems like you didn't even look at the code when trying, stil asking about the code (still not looked at the code), that's why im saying

Comment: I did look at it and thought it was strange how it was written, that's why I said that I didn't get how out and out_1 worked in the script, but then again, I'm not really good at R yet and thought that maybe what you did was ok only that something was missing. Btw, myvector_1 should also be defined previously. Just ran the function and seemed to work, took lot more than 5 secs though. Thank you very much, and bare in mind that this is the first time I post, so apologies for any inconvenience.

Comment: I see. How long did it take btw? The difference could be due to processor speeds, and by the way. Always  use the for loop for such big data, while loop isn't created for iterating through data anyway, it has a completely different purpose but can be used for the exact same purpose anyways. CPU time for the while loop to complete is 20 times faster than the for loop :) Just bare this in your mind

Comment: Probably want to consider using `data.table` if you can for speed and vectorisation.